# trying to iterate 3d array | undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multidimensional-array, each

what i'm making wrong?
The first 7 lines from the Array i can iterate but when i'm trying to open the another dimension than i receive an error.

**My Code**

```
require 'rest-client'

class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def listings
     url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/'
     response = RestClient.get(url)
     @jsonData = JSON.parse(response)
   end
end
```

api_controller works

```
<h1>LISTING </h1>

<%  @jsonData["data"].each do |coin| %>
        <%coin.each do |id| %>
        Name: <%= id["name"] %> <br />
        Symbol: <% id["symbol"] %><br />
        Website_slug: <% id["website_slug"] %><br />
        Rank: <% id["rank"] %><br />
        Circulating_supply: <% id["circulating_supply"] %><br />
        total_supply: <% id["total_supply"] %><br />
        max_supply: <% id["max_supply"] %><br />
```

till here it works

begin here it not works

```
        <%id["quotes"].each do |quotes| %>
        <%quotes.each do |usd| %>
        Price: <% usd["price"] %><br />
        Volume24h: <%= usd["volume_24h"] %><br />
        Market_cap: <%= usd["market_cap"] %><br />
        Change_1he: <%= usd["pricpercent_change_1he"] %><br />
        Change_24h: <%= usd["percent_change_24h"] %><br />
        Change_7d: <%= usd["percent_change_7d"] %><br />
            <%end%>
        <%end%>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

{"1"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Bitcoin", "symbol"=>"BTC", "website_slug"=>"bitcoin", "rank"=>1, "circulating_supply"=>17298850.0, "total_supply"=>17298850.0, "max_supply"=>21000000.0, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>6592.56514166, "volume_24h"=>3990509859.95985, "market_cap"=>114043795501.0, "percent_change_1h"=>-0.31, "percent_change_24h"=>-0.36, "percent_change_7d"=>-0.61}}, "last_updated"=>1538393012}, "1027"=>{"id"=>1027, "name"=>"Ethereum", "symbol"=>"ETH", "website_slug"=>"ethereum", "rank"=>2, "circulating_supply"=>102298658.0, "total_supply"=>102298658.0, "max_supply"=>nil, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>229.147840966, "volume_24h"=>1701049487.13546, "market_cap"=>23441516679.0, "percent_change_1h"=>-0.8, "percent_change_24h"=>-2.56, "percent_change_7d"=>-2.44}}, "last_updated"=>1538393021}, "52"=>{"id"=>52, "name"=>"XRP", "symbol"=>"XRP", "website_slug"=>"ripple", "rank"=>3, "circulating_supply"=>39870907279.0, "total_supply"=>99991836919.0, "max_supply"=>100000000000.0, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>0.5790784377, "volume_24h"=>1229031882.79177, "market_cap"=>23088382697.0, "percent_change_1h"=>-1.6, "percent_change_24h"=>-4.58, "percent_change_7d"=>7.96}}, "last_updated"=>1538393043}, "1831"=>{"id"=>1831, "name"=>"Bitcoin Cash", "symbol"=>"BCH", "website_slug"=>"bitcoin-cash", "rank"=>4, "circulating_supply"=>17378475.0, "total_supply"=>17378475.0, "max_supply"=>21000000.0, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>532.361000338, "volume_24h"=>480935803.85542, "market_cap"=>9251622335.0, "percent_change_1h"=>-0.78, "percent_change_24h"=>-1.57, "percent_change_7d"=>13.15}}, "last_updated"=>1538393013}, "1765"=>{"id"=>1765, "name"=>"EOS", "symbol"=>"EOS", "website_slug"=>"eos", "rank"=>5, "circulating_supply"=>906245118.0, "total_supply"=>1006245120.0, "max_supply"=>nil, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>5.6494577239, "volume_24h"=>822687391.374753, "market_cap"=>5119793479.0, "percent_change_1h"=>-0.53, "percent_change_24h"=>-3.01, "percent_change_7d"=>-1.66}}, "last_updated"=>1538393011}, "512"=>{"id"=>512, "name"=>"Stellar", "symbol"=>"XLM", "website_slug"=>"stellar", "rank"=>6, "circulating_supply"=>18789958255.0, "total_supply"=>104323820467.0, "max_supply"=>nil, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>0.261922298, "volume_24h"=>67633971.9905846, "market_cap"=>4921509046.0, "percent_change_1h"=>0.14, "percent_change_24h"=>1.03, "percent_change_7d"=>-0.49}}, "last_updated"=>1538392997}, "2"=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Litecoin", "symbol"=>"LTC", "website_slug"=>"litecoin", "rank"=>7, "circulating_supply"=>58532552.0, "total_supply"=>58532552.0, "max_supply"=>84000000.0, "quotes"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>60.7806370254, "volume_24h"=>461333051.026648, "market_cap"=>3557645805.0, "percent_change_1h"=>-0.07, "percent_change_24h"=>-1.17, "percent_change_7d"=>4.09}},

Comment: Can you do `raise @jsonData["data"].inspect` after `@jsonData = JSON.parse(response)` and paste the output in the question?

Comment: i got the Error: RuntimeError in ApiController#listings and got listed all the Coins/Tokens

Comment: yeah, copy that and paste in the question.

Comment: I did but only a part because it have more than 40'000 signs and i can only post with 30'000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code and feedback please :)

```
<h1>LISTING </h1>

<%  @jsonData.fetch('data', {}).each do |id, coin| %>
  Name: <%= coin['name'] %> <br />
  Symbol: <%= coin['symbol'] %> <br />
  Website_slug: <%= coin['website_slug'] %> <br />
  Rank: <%= coin['rank'] %> <br />
  Circulating_supply: <%= coin['circulating_supply'] %> <br />
  total_supply: <%= coin['total_supply'] %> <br />
  max_supply: <%= coin['max_supply'] %> <br />
  Price: <%= coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'price') %> <br />
  Volume24h: <%= coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'volume_24h') %> <br />
  Market_cap: <%= coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'market_cap') %> <br />
  Change_1he: <%= coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'pricpercent_change_1he') %> <br />
  Change_24h: <%= coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'percent_change_24h') %> <br />
  Change_7d: <%= coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'percent_change_7d') %> <br />
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

---

This is a sample of your JSON:

```js
{
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "symbol":"BTC",
         "website_slug":"bitcoin",
         "rank":1,
         "circulating_supply":17298850.0,
         "total_supply":17298850.0,
         "max_supply":21000000.0,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":6592.56514166,
               "volume_24h":3990509859.95985,
               "market_cap":114043795501.0,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.31,
               "percent_change_24h":-0.36,
               "percent_change_7d":-0.61
            }
         },
         "last_updated":1538393012
      },
      "1027":{
         "id":1027,
         "name":"Ethereum",
         "symbol":"ETH",
         "website_slug":"ethereum",
         "rank":2,
         "circulating_supply":102298658.0,
         "total_supply":102298658.0,
         "max_supply":null,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":229.147840966,
               "volume_24h":1701049487.13546,
               "market_cap":23441516679.0,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.8,
               "percent_change_24h":-2.56,
               "percent_change_7d":-2.44
            }
         },
         "last_updated":1538393021
      },
      "52":{
         "id":52,
         "name":"XRP",
         "symbol":"XRP",
         "website_slug":"ripple",
         "rank":3,
         "circulating_supply":39870907279.0,
         "total_supply":99991836919.0,
         "max_supply":100000000000.0,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":0.5790784377,
               "volume_24h":1229031882.79177,
               "market_cap":23088382697.0,
               "percent_change_1h":-1.6,
               "percent_change_24h":-4.58,
               "percent_change_7d":7.96
            }
         },
         "last_updated":1538393043
      },
      "1831":{
         "id":1831,
         "name":"Bitcoin Cash",
         "symbol":"BCH",
         "website_slug":"bitcoin-cash",
         "rank":4,
         "circulating_supply":17378475.0,
         "total_supply":17378475.0,
         "max_supply":21000000.0,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":532.361000338,
               "volume_24h":480935803.85542,
               "market_cap":9251622335.0,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.78,
               "percent_change_24h":-1.57,
               "percent_change_7d":13.15
            }
         },
         "last_updated":1538393013
      },
      "1765":{
         "id":1765,
         "name":"EOS",
         "symbol":"EOS",
         "website_slug":"eos",
         "rank":5,
         "circulating_supply":906245118.0,
         "total_supply":1006245120.0,
         "max_supply":null,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":5.6494577239,
               "volume_24h":822687391.374753,
               "market_cap":5119793479.0,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.53,
               "percent_change_24h":-3.01,
               "percent_change_7d":-1.66
            }
         },
         "last_updated":1538393011
      },
      "512":{
         "id":512,
         "name":"Stellar",
         "symbol":"XLM",
         "website_slug":"stellar",
         "rank":6,
         "circulating_supply":18789958255.0,
         "total_supply":104323820467.0,
         "max_supply":null,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":0.261922298,
               "volume_24h":67633971.9905846,
               "market_cap":4921509046.0,
               "percent_change_1h":0.14,
               "percent_change_24h":1.03,
               "percent_change_7d":-0.49
            }
         },
         "last_updated":1538392997
      },
      "2":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"Litecoin",
         "symbol":"LTC",
         "website_slug":"litecoin",
         "rank":7,
         "circulating_supply":58532552.0,
         "total_supply":58532552.0,
         "max_supply":84000000.0,
         "quotes":{
            "USD":{
               "price":60.7806370254,
               "volume_24h":461333051.026648,
               "market_cap":3557645805.0,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.07,
               "percent_change_24h":-1.17,
               "percent_change_7d":4.09
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Following this json you can see that there are no arrays `[]` it just a nested hashes `{}` so no need for all of your loops. For ex. to get the price you need to do something like: `@jsonData['data']['1']['quotes']['USD']['price']`

This path `['data']['1']['quotes']['USD']['price']` is all static, which means it will be the same for every `coin`. the only dynamic/changing part is `['1']`. Sometimes it will be `['1']`, `['1027']`, `['52']`, etc.

So in my code you can see that I access all of the data staticly but only for the `IDs` I had to loop over it but this loop will be over `key => value` because as mentioned before we are dealing with hashes not arrays.

So when I did `<%  @jsonData.fetch('data', {}).each do |id, coin| %>`:

- `id` has the value of `'1'`.
- `coin` has the structure of the coin (you can staticlly retrieve any piece of data like `coin.dig('quotes', 'USD', 'price')` for ex.

What you where doing:

`<%  @jsonData.['data'].each do |coin| %>`:

- `coin` will be `['1', 'structure of the coin here']`
- when you do `coin['name']` this will return nil but won't fail. At this point you thought it's working but it is not.

Comment: but i would like to understand why my idea didnt work its look good and the first part worked. maybe you can tell me

Comment: Yes, I'll tell you :) I'll update my post now with more details. you can mark my answer as correct if it did solve your issue and I'll update with more details now!

Comment: @HenrikZakaryan about the `price` value, it does not work because I had a typo `<%` instead of `<%=`. Just add the `=` and it should work :)

Comment: yes i saw it, because that i deleted the comment^^. Thank you very much.